# Is there any merit about assembly language?

Tags: linux, assembly

I heard some of developers use assembly language in embedded system.

I wonder what merit they have from learning assembly language and what field use assembly language.

Do you have any experience?

Comment: Assembly is mainly used in the hardware industry. It's also great for programming language design if you have the patience.

Comment: Assembler is basically machine code enhanced for human readability. That said it is obvious that you can implement logic with top most efficiency, though that comes with the downside of a language that lacks all features todays higher programming languages offer. So its usage _might_ make sense in some very special situation like extremely limited memory space or computation power.

Comment: @DarmaniLink Really? AFAIK assembly language is not really used in hardware industry and definitively it has nothing to do with programming language design.

Comment: The main use for knowing assembly language is to make sense of performance-counter data, and to tune code based on looking at compiler output.  It's also used to write hand-tuned versions of extremely important standard-library functions like `memcpy` and `strlen`.  Also, of course, most compiler developers have to understand asm to make sense of the output the compiler produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need for assembly code is proportional to the lack of *specific* compiler support.

Embedded systems are tailored to specific needs, for example Texas Instruments DSP have some "exotic" address modes, like [circular and bit reversing addressing modes](https://web.engr.illinois.edu/~thnguyn2/DSP%20Lab/AddressModes.pdf) that are absent into other architectures.
The C language cannot address all these differences in a standard way.

However the C standard doesn't forbid vendor extensions and compilers targeting specific environments come with built-in functions with the purpose of exposing some low-level functionality.  These functions are called **intrinsics** and being non standard reserved keywords, they start with an underscore.

For example, the [TMSxC6000 Optimization Manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru187o/spru187o.pdf) lists the intrinsics at *7.5.4*.
One very common operation done in DSP is *saturated addition* where in a *n* bits word (2<sup>n</sup> - 1) + 1 = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 as opposed to (2<sup>n</sup> - 1) + 1 = 0 for the usual modular addition.
In TI C dialect this translates to

```
int x1, x2, y;
y = _sadd(x1, x2);   //_sadd mimics the name of sadd assembly instruction
```

With the opportune intrinsics you can avoid assembly language at all.

---

There are however at least *three* situations where assembly language is still needed:

1. *No adequate intrinsics are present.*
   The programmer is forced to fallback to assembly.
2. *The compiler is known particularly bad at optimizing code and you want to write critical part by your self.*
   Think at least thrice before taking this path.
3. *You need to use the same C code base for different platforms.*
   This is the case of the Linux kernel for example, where they use a small portion of assembly to "abstract" the execution environment enough to be handled with mostly pure C code.
   Often the diversities are so accentuated that simply calling intrinsics is not enough, a different management is needed instead, an abstraction.